# Конфликт обьявлений mySQL connector + C++

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

Пытаюсь использовать коннектер MySQL и C++
среда : 
Windows 10
Code::Blocks 17.12
MySQL 8.0
MySQL Connector C++ 8.0

Понял, что идет переобьявление чего-то. При попытке "прокомментировать" код из коннектора, который и переобьявляет эти "инты" IDE не реагирует, а при попытке сохранения изменений, выскакивает ошибка(аж два раза), что такойто такойто файл, вы сохранить(==изменить?) не можете.

> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++14 -O2 -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysql" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysqlx" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc\cppconn" -c C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\lib64" -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14" -o bin\Release\SQLfinal_connect.exe obj\Release\main.o  -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient mysqlpp mysqlclient nsl z m -s
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/warning.h:40:0,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:39,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:36,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/sqlstring.h:46:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/sqlstring.h:47:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4251)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/sqlstring.h:51:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:39:0,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:36,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/warning.h:46:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/variant.h:44:0,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:41,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:36,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:65:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:69:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:70:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4275)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:75:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:0:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:183:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:184:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4251)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:188:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:194:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:195:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4251)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:201:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/resultset.h:36:0,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:8:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/config.h:101:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
>    typedef __int32   int32_t;
>                      ^
>   In file included from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/stdint.h:9:0,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/cstdint:41,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:380,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:3:
>   C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/include/stdint.h:31:14: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
>    typedef int  int32_t;
>                 ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/resultset.h:36:0,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:8:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/config.h:105:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'
>    typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
>                             ^
>   In file included from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/stdint.h:9:0,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/cstdint:41,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:380,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:3:
>   C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/include/stdint.h:32:20: note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'
>    typedef unsigned   uint32_t;
>                       ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/statement.h:36:0,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:9:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/config.h:101:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
>    typedef __int32   int32_t;
>                      ^
>   In file included from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/stdint.h:9:0,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/cstdint:41,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:380,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:3:
>   C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/include/stdint.h:31:14: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
>    typedef int  int32_t;
>                 ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/statement.h:36:0,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:9:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/config.h:105:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'
>    typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
>                             ^
>   In file included from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/stdint.h:9:0,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/cstdint:41,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:380,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
>                    from C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:3:
>   C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/include/stdint.h:32:20: note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'
>    typedef unsigned   uint32_t;
>                       ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:25:19: warning: unused variable 'stmt' [-Wunused-variable]
>      sql::Statement *stmt;
>                      ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:26:19: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
>      sql::ResultSet *res;
>                      ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:34:1: error: expected 'catch' before 'cout'
>    cout << endl;
>    ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:34:1: error: expected '(' before 'cout'
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:34:1: error: 'cout' does not name a type
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:34:6: error: expected ')' before '<<' token
>    cout << endl;
>         ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:34:6: error: expected '{' before '<<' token
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:34:6: error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token

Comment: Зачем вы меняете код библиотеки? Это защита от *дурака*. Вы можете ненароком сломать бинарную связи в этой библиотеке, если она скопилирована как распространяемая.

Comment: А что мне тогда делать? Коннектор скачанный с официального, был автоматически установлен, либа внутри него, переобьявляет чтото из стандартной либы, решил "потормошить" меньшее зло, либу коннектора

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтож, прошел день усердного гугления, и он дал свои результаты, спешу поделиться как решить эту проблему.

Необходимо указать macro definition

```
HAVE_INT8_T=1
HAVE_STDINT=1
CPPCONN_DONT_TYPEDEF_MS_TYPES_TO_C99_TYPES=1
```